# convert lat lon stored in hex to float

Tags: c, gps

I have packet with gps coordinations, where 12-15B is lat and 16-19B is lon.
This data is type of i32.
I have already tried divided it with 1 000 000 or 30 000, but still I got huge number.
Can anyone help me, how can i get from these coordinates float number of lat and lon?

lat: A3A3 EE02 should be around 48° (i dont know the exact position only near)
lon: 4C90 FD 00 should be around 16°

[image: packet data with gps coordinates]

Comment: You need to find the documentation for the GPS unit, and read what it *actually* sends. Even if the data is *serialized* as a 32-bit integer it might not actually be that.

Comment: gps coordination has resolution  10^-6 degree

Comment: The packet looks like it could be BINEX format.  The GPSTK library may be of use.

Comment: It would help if you *knew* / let us know too, where the decoded coordinates should be, besides "somewhere on Earth".

Comment: Also, please copy the *actual* octets into the question, instead of just a screenshot!

Comment: i resolved it, problem was that: data is stored in the reverse order, so a3a3ee02 should be 02eea3a3, its really strange to me why

Comment: You got bitten by *Endianness* .. You must be executing on a 32 bit LE architecture

Comment: which NEMA message is that GPS data?

Comment: I dont which NMEA message is used, I only received packets from gps tracker and Ive got datagram of what each byte in payload mean.